# React - dynamic input fields based on count

Tags: reactjs

I want create the textfields based on the count entered by the user. I have gone through many related questions, I cannot find the result as I want.

For Example: If the user enter 5 as input.. I want to create 5 text boxes for entering 5 people Name and Mobile.

How can I achieve this?

TextField to get count

```
  <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                      <TextField
                        id="sp_Inhouse"
                        label="Number of Pilots Available "
                        type="number"
                        fullWidth
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={this.state.sp_Inhousecount}
                        error={!!this.state.sp_InhouseError}
                        helperText={this.state.sp_InhouseError}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeInhouse}
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                      />
                    </GridItem>
```

Tried adding the textboxes based on button click. It works fine. but I want the result as explained.

```
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                       <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleCreatePilots}>
                      <AddIcon />  Add Pilots
                      </Button>
                      {this.state.inhouse.map((index) => {
                        return (
                          <div key={index}>
                          <TextField
                            id="sp_Name"

                            label="Name "
                            type="number"
                            fullWidth
                          />
 <TextField
                            id="sp_Mobile"

                            label="Name "
                            type="number"
                            fullWidth
                          />
                          </div>
                        )
                      })
                      }
                    </GridItem>
```

```
 handleCreatePilots=()=>{
    this.setState({
      inhouse:[...this.state.inhouse,'']
    })
  }
```

Comment: no.. inhouse: []

Comment: `inhouse` is a different value or are you saving the total number in that state variable?

Comment: here it is different value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the number entered by the user.

```
const inputs = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= this.state.total; i++) {
  inputs.push(
    <input name={`input-${i}`} onChange={this.onChange} />
  )
}
```

Render inputs

```
render() {
  return (
   ....
    {inputs}
  ...
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      total: 0,
      totalInput: '',
      show: false,
    };
  }

  add = () => {
    this.setState({
      total: this.state.totalInput
    })
  }

  showValues = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    })
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {

    const inputs = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= this.state.total; i++) {
      inputs.push(
        <input name={`input-${i}`} onChange={this.onChange} />
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({ totalInput: e.target.value})} value={this.state.totalInput}  placeholder="Enter Number" />
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
        <br />
        {inputs}
         <br />
        <button onClick={this.showValues}>Show Inputs values</button>
        { this.state.show && 
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)}</pre>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. Other refactor may be required.

**Working link**
https://jsfiddle.net/ogmv3wpu/1/

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state= {
   inputSize: 0
  }
 }
 
 handleOnChange(value){
 this.setState({
 inputSize: value.target.value
 });
 }
 
 renderInputs(value){
  const inputs=[];
  for(let i=0; i<value; i++){
    inputs.push(<div key={i}><input  value={Name}}type="text" name="quantity"/></div>)
  }
  return inputs;
 }
 
  render() {
  console.log(this.state.inputSize);
    return (<div>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99999" onChange={(value)=>this.handleOnChange(value)}/>
    <div>
    {this.renderInputs(this.state.inputSize)}
    </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, hope you could find my answer helpful.