# How to read field input into a react state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state

In the web app that I'm working on, I'm giving the user an option to select the number of machines they have inside a facility. Based on the selected number, a respective number of form fields appear to the user. I managed to configure the interface using this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373185/react-dynamic-input-fields-based-on-count). I'm confused now on how to read the input values of each field into a dynamic state array?
this is the code that I'm working on currently [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogmv3wpu/1/).

```
handleOnChange(value) {
  this.setState({ inputSize: value.target.value });
}

renderInputs(value) {
  const inputs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    inputs.push(
      <div>
        <Input
          value={this.state.sortingMachines[i]}
          onChange={(event) =>
            this.props.setState({ sortingMachines: event.target.value })
          }
          icon="ethereum"
        />
      </div>
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.sortingMachines[i]);
    }
  }
  return inputs;
}

render() {
  const { sortingMachines } = this.state;

  console.log(this.state.inputSize);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Field width={6}>
        <label>Sorting Machines Address</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="quantity"
          min="1"
          max="7"
          onChange={(value) => this.handleOnChange(value)}
        />
        <div>{this.renderInputs(this.state.inputSize)}</div>
      </Form.Field>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make default the `sortingMachines` array in state to an empty array and then just make sure you're setting the `ith` element to the value you want in the change handler (after copying the array);

```
constructor() {
  this.state  = {
    sortingMachines: []
  }
}

renderInputs(value) {
  const inputs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    inputs.push(
      <div>
        <Input
          value={this.state.sortingMachines[i]}
          onChange={(event) =>
            const newSortingMachines = [...this.state.sortingMachines];
            newSortingMachines[i] = event.target.value;
            this.setState({ sortingMachines: newSortingMachines })
          }
          icon="ethereum"
        />
      </div>
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.sortingMachines[i]);
    }
  }
  return inputs;
}
```

Now, the `sortingMachine` value for each element will be at its corresponding array position.

**Edit:** One small word of caution here is that, if you delete one of your elements, you'll need to make sure you shift your `sortingMachines` array accordingly. This might not be a concern for your use case, but if it is, then arrays might *not* be the best solution. If you have some kind of unique identifier for each element, you could use an object structure.